# Especify union type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have something like this:

```
interface ISome {
    myValue: number | string;
    // some more members
}
```

And I have a function that will acept an `ISome` whose `myValue` is a number, and use it like:

```
function (some: ISome): number { // I accept only ISome with myValue type number
    return some.myValue + 3;
}
```

The typescript compiler complains as expected because `some.myValue` is number or string.
Of course I could use a union type to check:

```
function (some: ISome): number { // I could use a guard
    if (typeof some.myValue === "number") {
        return some.myValue + 3;
    }
}
```

But this is not what I want as I need to do this very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the union type with an intersection type and specify the type for `myValue` there:

```
function someFunction(some: ISome & {  
    myValue: number
}): number {
    return some.myValue + 3; // No error
}
```